# Troubles compiling subitems in Beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize

I am using \documentclass{beamer} in LaTeX and for some reason my Editor returns an error in the subsequent code: 
'Undefined control sequence \end{frame}.

```
   \begin{itemize}
\item Comparative measurements: 
\begin{itemize}
\item Two-tone input signal
\item Carrier frequency at \Si{11.725}{\giga\hertz}
\item Bandwidth of \SI{5}{\mega\hertz}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is the wrong command `\Si` if you change that to `\SI` everything should be fine.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Comparative measurements: 
\begin{itemize}
\item Two-tone input signal
\item Carrier frequency at \SI{11.725}{\giga\hertz}
\item Bandwidth of \SI{5}{\mega\hertz}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```